# distCoeff setting for solvePnP in opencv

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I tried solvePnP in opencv3.0 with Qt
When I didn't specify distCoeff, the program compiled successfully and I can get the result, like this

```
...
cv::Mat camera_matrix = cv::Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
camera_matrix.at<double>(0, 2) = image_.width() / 2;
camera_matrix.at<double>(1, 2) = image_.height() / 2;
camera_matrix.at<double>(0, 0) = focal_t;
camera_matrix.at<double>(1, 1) = focal_t;
...
cv::Mat dist_coeffs;
...
cv::solvePnP(object_points, image_points, camera_matrix,
                             dist_coeffs, rotation, translation);
```

But when I initialized the distCoef with specific value,

```
 ... 
 cv::Mat camera_matrix = cv::Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
 camera_matrix.at<double>(0, 2) = image_.width() / 2;
 camera_matrix.at<double>(1, 2) = image_.height() / 2;
 camera_matrix.at<double>(0, 0) = focal_t; camera_matrix.at<double>(1,
 1) = focal_t; 
 ...
 double dist_coeff[] = {k1, k2, p1, p2, k3}; 
 cv::Mat dist_coeffs = cv::Mat(5, 1, CV_64F, dist_coeff); 
 ...
 cv::solvePnP(object_points, image_points, camera_matrix,
                              dist_coeffs, rotation, translation);
```

it failed, the application output is

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/allanna/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/modules/calib3d/src/solvepnp.cpp:61: error: (-215) npoints >= 0 && npoints == std::max(ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_32F), ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_64F)) in function solvePnP
```

How does that happen? Thank u
And if I specify distCoeff like this,

```
double dist_coeff[] = {k1, k2, p1, p2};
cv::Mat dist_coeffs = cv::Mat(4, 1, CV_64F, dist_coeff);
```

The application output is

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'   what():  /home/allanna/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/modules/calib3d/src/solvepnp.cpp:61: error: (-215) npoints >= 0 && npoints == std::max(ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_32F), ipoints.checkVector(2, CV_64F)) in function solvePnP
```